# PyQT5 fileDialoge for file save

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to use a QFileDialog to prompt a user to provide a filename and location to save a video file at. I played around with the QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName, but I was interested in using some of the options, i want to give only directory and it save according to the title of the video.

```
save_location = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,caption="Save as", directory='.',filter="Video File (*.mp4*)")
    #save_location_path = str(save_location)

    self.lineEdit_2.setText(save_location[0])
```

Comment: if you dont let your user change any aspect just dont use dialog,do you want directory to be standard?

Comment: I want to Choose only directory "

Comment: Then just use dialog for directory choosing,or disregard the return of your dialog fle_name and use what you want

Comment: Or use [QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory). Otherwise, subclass QFileDialog and set your own options.

Comment: thank you can you share any example

Comment: Thank you very much i understand it its very helpful for me